# jQuery - Disabling checkbox & adding attribute on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I need checkboxes + table rows that share attributes to be enabled once the first checkbox has been ticked. (`id` for the table row + `class` for checkbox).

This is only half working

My problem is that if you have multiple boxes selected and uncheck just one, all of the checkboxes and table rows lose the `disabled` attribute.

https://jsfiddle.net/a1p7an7o/

HTML

```
            <tr id="IN-HOUSE">
                <input onchange="check();" class="IN-HOUSE" name="bill[]" type="checkbox">
            <label for="Bill?">Bill?</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
    function check(){
$('input[name*=bill]').change(function() {
   $t = $(this);
   var $th = $(this).attr('class');
      $c = $("tr[id!='"+$th+"']");

   if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

     $('input[name*=bill]').each(function() {
       if ($(this).attr('class') != $th) {
         $(this).not($t).prop('disabled', true);
        $c.not($t).addClass( "disable" );

       }
     });
   } else {
     $('input[name*=bill]').each(function() {

       if ($(this).attr('class') != $th) {
         $(this).not($t).prop('disabled', false);
         $("tr[id!='"+$th+"']").removeClass("disable");

       }
     });
   }
 });
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle please?

Comment: @lipp https://jsfiddle.net/a1p7an7o/

Comment: when you enable/check one checkbox want to add a class to the respective row and remove this class when the checkbox is unchecked?

Comment: @lipp for example if `client2` is checked the others are disabled. if i select `in-house`, `Client2` is disabled but if I have two `in-house` selected and deselect one, it allows me to select `client2` this should not be possible unless no box is checked